# Vaadin 23 Grid: how to sync DataCommunicator with DataProvider?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin23

In a Vaadin 23.3.10 Grid I'd like to select a row that is next to a row that was selected before. Therefore I read the items from the DataCommunicator. Most cases work fine, but the DataCommunicator seems to be not in sync with the DataProvider after calling `dataProvider.remove(x)` and `dataProvider.refreshAll()`.

The button is plugin-based so the code snippet that selects the next row doesn't know whether some other plugin that ran before removed an item from the grid.

Here is a code example that only shows that a DataProvider and a DataCommunicator are out of sync after removing an item from the DataProvider and that the DataCommunicator is not consistent in its own:

```
@Route("sandbox")
public class SandboxView extends VerticalLayout {

private class Item {
    String name;
    private Item(String name) {this.name=name;}
}

public SandboxView() {
    // Generate some items
    Item a = new Item("a");
    Item b = new Item("b");
    Item c = new Item("c");
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(a);
    items.add(b);
    items.add(c);
    ListDataProvider<Item> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(items);
    
    // Create a grid
    Grid<Item> grid = new Grid<>();
    grid.setItems(dataProvider);
    grid.addColumn(item -> item.name).setHeader("Name");
    this.add(grid);
    
    // Create a button that removes an item from the grid
    Button button = new Button("Remove item A");
    button.addClickListener(event -> {
            DataCommunicator<Item> dataCommunicator = grid.getDataCommunicator();
            printDataCommunicatorItemInfo(dataCommunicator);
            // Output is as expected:
            // 3 items
            // Item: a
            // Item: b
            // Item: c
            
            dataProvider.getItems().remove(a);
            printDataCommunicatorItemInfo(dataCommunicator);
            // Output is still the same:
            // 3 items
            // Item: a
            // Item: b
            // Item: c
            
            dataProvider.refreshAll();
            printDataCommunicatorItemInfo(dataCommunicator);
            // ## UNEXPECTED ##
            // Output is out of sync:
            // 2 items
            // Item: a
            // Item: b
        }
    );
    this.add(button);
}

private void printDataCommunicatorItemInfo(DataCommunicator<Item> dataCommunicator) {
    System.out.println(dataCommunicator.getItemCount()+" items");
    for (int i=0;i<dataCommunicator.getItemCount();i++) {
        System.out.println("Item: "+dataCommunicator.getItem(i).name);
    }
}

}
```

The problem is that `dataCommunicator.getItemCount()` returns the reduced number of items (2) but `dataCommunicator.getItem(...)` still returns the removed item (a).

Question: How can I force the dataCommunicator to get in sync again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vaadin 23, you can get the next item from the GridListDataView.

For example:

```
GridListDataView<Person> dataView = grid.setItems(DataProvider.ofCollection(PersonUtil.buildPersons())); 
Person item; // item a 
Optional<Person> nextItem = dataView.getNextItem(item); dataView.removeItem(item);
```

I'm not really sure about the dataCommunicator issue. I didn't look into the issue in details but you don't need to use it.

Comment: Great! There is another method dataView.getPreviousItem. I use it if nextItem contains no Item (e.g. when the removed item was at the end of the list).

Answer (score 4):

`refreshAll()` only sets a flag that the data should be recomputed but it doesn't do the actual recompute. This is a performance optimization in case `refreshAll()` is called multiple times in a row.

The recomputation is scheduled using `UI.beforeClientResponse` and those are run in the order they have been submitted for a given component. This means that you can add your own logic after the recomputation with something like `UI.getCurrent().beforeClientResponse(grid, context -> printDataCommunicatorItemInfo(dataCommunicator));`.